# Why can't I connect to Chrome 200 OK server from another network device?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, google-chrome, router, webserver

I use the 200 OK Web Server extension for Chrome, which serves web pages from a local folder over the network, using HTTP. I can access the server normally from the browser of the computer that runs the server, but trying to access it from the browser (also Chrome) of a mobile device in the same network fails (I get a "can't connect" error).

**Things I've already checked/tried:**

- The option to allow access from the same network is checked
- Both devices are connected to the same network
- I've marked my network as "Private" (was public)
- I've made a firewall rule to allow the specific port
- I've made sure the router doesn't have client isolation on.

**My question:**

Having already tried the above, what other reason would there be for this to fail? Am I missing something?

Comment: Does the list of web server IPs (under "web server URLs") in the extension's menu have your machine's private IP listed?

Comment: It does. Before the option to enable the local network it's simply the localhost (127.0.0.1), and then, after checking the option and restarting the server, it also shows the local IP. That's the one I'm trying, without success (not forgetting to add the port number at the end)

Comment: This may sound silly, but try turning off the mobile data connection on your phone. It is possible that it's prioritizing the WAN link. Even better would be trying with another PC, the troubleshooting tools available to you will be much better.

Comment: Have you checked your computers firewall?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, yes, I've checked the firewall. As for the mobile, the data is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as is often the case, it was down to a very simple error related to lack of concentration.

Turns out, I had accidentally added the firewall rule to the *outbound* rather than the inbound set. Adding the rule (opening the port) to inbound worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pinging the you host in any direction? From a computer can't you ping any of the devices?

Have you tried connecting Via IP or hostname? Always troubleshoot whilst connecting Via IP and not via hostname.

Is network isolation turned on on your router? On LAN you do not need any port forwarding rules, this is typically to provide external access to a network resource.

Does any other service work from your phone?

Also make sure data is turned off of your phone and purely wifi, it may use your data connection if there is any communication issue.

Comment: The phone works normally, mobile data is off, and, as stated in the question, network isolation is off. I tried to connect using the IP